# How to get owner of the deployed Program in Anchor. Is there any method I can use to get the Owner with in the Program the way we have in Ethereum?

Tags: anchor

I want to get the owner account in Solana program written using anchor, however I didn't find any method by which I can find the owner the way we have in Ethereum. Can someone help me to find the owner in Solana Program.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what do you mean, please? Is it like this?: https://grizzlypeaksoftware.com/articles?id=6NvaOcWdWhwGEKbILwVUKr

Answer (score 3):

If by "owner" you mean the upgrade authority of a program, then you can get the account data of the program and deserialize those bytes with:

```
async function getProgramAuthority(c: Connection, programId: PublicKey): Promise<PublicKey> {
  const info = await c.getAccountInfo(programId)
  const dataAddress = new PublicKey(info.data.subarray(4))

  const dataAcc = await c.getAccountInfo(dataAddress)
  return new PublicKey(dataAcc.data.subarray(13, 45))
}
```

This is an optional field though, so if `dataAcc.data[12] === 1` then the next 32 bytes `[13:45]` will be the upgrade authority, otherwise there is no active upgrade authority and the program is immutable.